# Excel Sheet: Count days a worker has worked

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I work in Sales and I have to count how many days has a worker worked. I currently struggle to come up with formula to count it.

My thought proces is that I made a column with all the workers in the company and in second colum I want to get amount of days they worked. From data via Countifs I can pull TOTAL of entries there are with their name but I can't filter it with function to get specific amount of days they worked.

Example 1 of Data per one person if filtered manually:

[image]

Example 2 of Data per multiple workers:

[image]

As you can see our data is giving me multiple entries with one name, so like "Joe" has a certain date multiple times in the Data but I only need to count it once so I get the "1" that he worked in that day.

I don't want to mess with the original data input, I'm putting it ofcourse in different sheet since the Data sheet is just where I get my information from.

I used this formula to get total amount of entries from data per worker.

`=COUNTIF(Data_All[Worker],[@Worker])`

And then I tried to appoint it to a single date and make a whole table just for one worker and it would give me entries per day.
`=COUNTIFS(Data_All[Worker],Sheet1!F2,Data_All[Datum],$H2)`

Here as an example it showed like "Joe has 9 entries on that specific date"

[image]

So in the end what I'm looking for is a way or formula to be able to filter it and be able to count days a worker has worked from all the data given.
I also apologize if its difficult to understand what I'm looking for but my English is not that good and I'm pretty novice in Excel and its formulas.

Thank you anyway for any response to my issue.

Comment: A count per worker per date....It really seems like you'd want to look into a pivot table to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pivot table. Put Worker on "row", Date on "value", then right click on any date in Pivot table and choose "Summarize value by" and choose "count". Now you can see if any value is insert more then one time for any Worker. Then just Filer worker and count how many rows are inserted. Grand total is counted.